# El directorio OUT de Intellij IDEA ignora una de las carpetas externas de src

Tags: javafx, intellij-idea, javafx-css

Me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto usando JAVAFX y tengo todos los recursos del aplicativo en un directorio llamado "assets" que se encuentra fuera del directorio src, cuando compilo el aplicativo, la carpeta assets no se encuentra dentro del directorio out y genera errores respecto a las rutas establecidas en el código ¿Alguien sabe de qué manera puedo agregar la carpeta en cuestión al directorio out para que se actualicen a la par?

Comment: ¿Qué estás utilizando para compilar?, ¿maven? De igual forma proporciona más información de tu pregunta

Comment: Estoy usando el compilador de Java
Para poner un caso específico
Uno de mis .fxml usa un CSS que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta assets que mencioné.
Cuando ejecuto el programa, los estilos no cargan e Intellij me devuelve este error:

Could not find stylesheet: file:/D:/NUEVO_PROYECTO/Proyecto-final-FBD/proyecto/out/production/assets/css/MP_CSS.css

La cuestión es que la carpeta assets no se crea nunca en out, puedo solucionarlo parcialmente copiando y pegando el directorio, pero los cambios no se sincronizan en out cuando los aplicó en el directorio original.

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré solucionarlo
Intellij provee una herramienta llamada "artifacts" que permite agregar carpetas y archivos de manera personalizada al directorio de compilación, siendo este out, creé un artifact al cuál le asigné la carpeta assets que me estaba dando problemas, cambié su ruta y el programa se ejecutó sin problemas:

[image: Creación del Artificat usando Project Structure]